# Adding a new folder to Komodo Edit

Tags: directory, komodo

I am new to Komodo Edit (version 5.2 for Linux) and wish to add a new "live" folder to my project. What I mean by that is, I want a new folder to not only appear within my Komodo project but also for that folder to be created in my computers file system. However when I choose to add a new item to my project and using the "add folder" option, the folder is only created within my project but not in my file system.  So it seems I am just creating a "virtual folder".  I also tried the "add live folder" option but it seems to be only able to add an existing folder.

I know this may seem a bit trivial, but I was expecting to be able to add a new system directory to my project using Komodo Edit without having to use the command line or computer browser.  This just seems a little inefficient.

Comment: Try asking in the official Komodo forum, http://community.activestate.com/forums/komodo

Answer (score 1):

Use the extension [JSDriveTree](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/jstreedrive). Once it's installed, restart Komodo and go to Projects=>Add=>New Live Folder, then click the button labeled 'Make New Folder'.